# Google Cloud Load balancer settings keep getting reset

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently setting up an environment to deploy an application on google cloud platform using kubernetes.

I tried setting up an Ingress to connect to my `NodePort` services with the following yaml config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "my-certificate"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        backend:
          serviceName: website
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /api/*
        backend:
          serviceName: api
          servicePort: 80
```

So `example.com` and all routes go to my `website` service, and all requests to `example.com/api/` go to my API app.

Only thing is I want all requests to be rewritten to my app as `/<endpoint>` instead of `/api/<endpoint>`. Just a few days back gcp added the ability to specify additional redirect and rewrite rules for load balancers, but it isn't available to be configured in YAML yet (as seen here: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/109).

Now I went to go manually configure the host rewrite through the cloud console. Once I save, the settings appear to get reverted back within about 10 minutes and I can't figure out why.

I also want to set up a http to https redirect rule, but I can't create these either because they seem to get reverted as well.

Could anybody explain why this is?

I'm not sure if it matters but I used `kubectl apply -f my-ingress.yaml` to create the ingress

Comment: Maybe the k8s cloud-controller is wrestling back control of the config? Ultimately when you are declaring the ingress controller you are instructing the cloud controller to go and configure GCP LB. I could be wrong, but maybe periodically it looks for deviation from its config and reapplied it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Alex Moore said - because the GCP LB is a K8s object it controls its configuration.

If you want to use features that cannot be configured inside K8s you should create the LB outside of K8s, create a nodePort service and point the GCP LB to the nodes.